# How to replace (drop and rename) a table without triggering constraints in postgres

Tags: postgresql, update, constraint, drop-table, rename

I have a table (**A**) that I need to reprocess from time to time.

Doing that using `update` or `upsert` is really slow, so, to make things faster, I decided to create a new table (**B**), copy all the rows from **A** to **B** with the updated values, drop **A** and rename **B** to **A**.

All of it works great and is pretty fast, except the final part when I try to drop **A** to replace it with **B**.

Basically I have other tables that have foreign key constraints with **A**, so when I try to drop **A**, Postgres will not allow.

Ex:

```sql
pacman_3_dev=*# drop table if exists public.entities;
ERROR:  cannot drop table entities because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  constraint records_grantee_entity_id_fkey on table raw.records depends on table entities
constraint records_grantor_entity_id_fkey on table raw.records depends on table entities
constraint properties_first_owner_entity_id_fkey on table properties depends on table entities
constraint skip_traces_entity_id_fkey on table skip_traces depends on table entities
constraint transactions_entity_id_fkey on table transactions depends on table entities
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
```

What would be the best approach for this case? Is my only option dropping all these constraints manually and then recreating them?

Is there any workaround to that? In the end both tables **A** and **B** have the same rows ids, so the foreign keys of the other tables should work just fine after I replace **A** with **B**.

Comment: Instead of creating a new table and dropping the old one, try to find out what causes the trouble and fix that. Perhaps all you need to do is tune autovacuum.